# Can you use something before your burn it in a challenge in Freemarket?

Tags: freemarket

On Freemarket page 29 it says you can burn resources to remove points from your opponent's hand. However, if tech or interface are reduced to zero, you can't use them until they are repaired or restored. But is it ok to burn technology or interface that you have already used during the current challenge? Or does using it normally somehow make it unburnable until the next challenge?

Comment: What is the link to this game?

Comment: http://projectdonut.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can engage tech, recalibrate, error correct, or burn as an action. If you burned something to 0, you can no longer use it. If you use something, you can burn it during the challenge as long as it has at least one point left to burn.